# How to fix labels in chart.js

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I am using chart.js for the first time for my project and when I passed my labels into the chart.js component, instead of taking strings like "sunday" and "monday" as labels, it takes "s" , "u", "n" ,"d" etc. How to fix this issue:
[image]

Code for the bar chart:

```
<template>
  <canvas :id="`myChart${id}`"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
export default {
  name: 'AnalysisBarChart',
  props: ['id', 'labels'],
  mounted() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart' + this.id).getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: this.id,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    myChart;
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

And I pass these labels:

```
labels: ['sunday', 'monday'],
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour only appears when you provide your labels array as a string instead of an array. So your labels array is not an array as you say it is but instead it is a string that looks like an array.

So you will need to convert that strong back to an array and then it will work as expected

Comment: How to strongly convert it?